# AVR USART Garbage Data

Tags: avr, atmega, uart

I have been having issues with my AVR USART. Using a PL2303 USB adapter with the following connections to the AVR

[image]

What I am seeing is

Garbage data (mostly of 0xFF or 0xF7 or 0xE7) even when the circuit is turned off (output below in HEX)

```
FF FF 7F 7F FF FF FF FF F7 F7 77 F7 FF 76 F6 FF F6 B7 FF FF E7 77 7F
FF EE FF FF 76 FF F7 F7 FF FB F7 FF FF FF F7 77 37 F7 77 FF 77 F7 FF
FF FF F7 FF FF EF F7 7F 7F 77 77 FF 77 FF 77 F7 7F 6F FF FE FF 7F F3
E7 FE E7 FF 77 FF 9F DF 94 EE FF FF EB BF FF 27 DA FF B7 FF FF 7F 6C
B9 FF 6F 6F 7F FF FE EF DB FF FE BF 74 FF F6 F7 F7 FF DE FB FF BF BF
B7 3F B4 FB 7F 6F 7F
```

When the circuit is on, this garbage data is interleaved with my regular output (below in ASCII to show my regular output interleaved with garbage)

```
Pro?yv2?[?o?[???rrent Time &n?m????????{??10:47:33
1/1/9???????????{3y 'm' &
'?'`???????????v<6>6{kk<11>s#?<3>????ow????o?????f<6>6{kk<11>s#?<3>??k??????????<27>?<3>accepted
??????????????n<22><27><27>+??+#`
```

This happens randomly. Somedays it would happen, then go away on its own and then come back again.

I am using **16 Mhz crystal**. **Baud rate 38400, Data 2, Parity None**. USART mode **asynchronous**

Comment: Could you replace the screenshots with the actual text that is on screen? The images are hard to read and use more screen real-estate than necessary. There must be a way to copy the text.

Comment: What baudrate are you using? What UART clock mode are you using, ×16 or ×4? Are you using internal resonator or a crystal?

Comment: @jippie images replaced with text & required USART information added

Comment: Is the ATMega328's ground connected to the PL2303 ground?  You need that connection to provide a reference for the data lines.

Comment: @PeterBennett. Yes it is. I overlooked it while drawing the circuit. circuit image updated

Comment: Can't say I've seen junk with a circuit that simple off before other than for a moment as it powers down. Did you have another adapter you can try? When it happens it might also be interesting to see what happens if you tie the receive line to ground (with the circuit off).

Comment: Is there long wires between the 2 components?

Comment: VDD_232 is connected to proper voltage level ?

Comment: this is quite weird. so I tested with another unit of pl2303. With the new unit everything was working okay but after couple of restarts of the system, same behaviour. also plugging the pl2303 directly into the breadboard (instead of a 20 cm wire connecting it to my breadboard) did not change the outcome

Comment: @PeterBennett. You were right. Went over my connections more thoroughly and discovered that the the side of the breadboard from where I was drawing the ground for PL2303 was not connected to the circuit ground properly. it was a loose cable.Thanks! Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: You should comment on the answer as well so that others can judge it fairly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the ATMega328's ground connected to the PL2303 ground? You need that connection to provide a reference for the data lines.

Comment: The original drawing did not show a ground connection between the ATMega and PL2303.  The OP added the ground connection in the drawing, and found a loose wire in his circuit.  Read all the comments on the original question.